# How to declare an item as a BigNumber with TypeScript & zod

Tags: typescript, types, zod, bignumber.js

I'm parsing input in TypeScript using zod, and attempting to replace the following interface with a zod type:

```
interface args {
    quantity: number;
    hugeNum: BigNumber;
}
```

Declaring this with zod, I get:

```
const numConstraints = z.number().min(1);
const parsedPriceType = z.bigint().optional();

const zArgs = z.object({
    quantity: numConstraints,
    parsedPrice?: parsedPriceType,
});

export type myArgs = z.infer<typeof zArgs>;
```

However, compiling this I get the following error:

```
        Types of property 'parsedPrice' are incompatible.
          Type 'BigNumber' is not assignable to type 'bigint'.
```

Is there a `BigNumber` equivalent in zod that I can use? Or is this a lost cause?

Comment: how about `z.instanceof(BigNumber)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const parsedPriceType = z.bigint().optional();
```

means an optional bigint, the primitive of the builtin [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) (zod might allow the wrapped version, might not, I don't know).

`BigNumber` comes from the [bignumber.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignumber.js) library, which isn't an ECMAScript standard or web standard, so zod doesn't come with a builtin checker for it (especially since that would add dependencies and/or peer dependencies).

If you want to have a `BigNumber` in your schema, use [`z.instanceOf`](https://zod.dev/?id=instanceof). That would look like

```
const parsedPriceType = z.instanceOf(BigNumber).optional();
```